# Is it legal to earn money via selling online currency (videogame)?

Tags: tax-law, currency, netherlands

(Europe/Netherlands)

Let's say I'm a World of Warcraft or Runescape player, in these games there are certain prices for gold, for example a X amount of ingame Runescape money might be worth a Y amount of real money. The game does not allow you to "Real-World trade" the money, this is written in the ToS you accept. Often getting caught leads to termination of ones account.

I have read this question and answer [Is legal to sell virtual goods?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8992/is-legal-to-sell-virtual-goods) but  I'm wondering about the legality of earning money this way. If this is not illegal how would you do this legally? I guess it would be comparable to earning tickets at a arcade (you don't have to pay to earn them) the arcade says you can't sell the tickets for money but you do so anyway.

Comment: I can't see how your question is different from the one you linked

Comment: That question replies that it's probably not illegal "How would do this legally" do just have to file it as profit made by a company owned by just you and then it's all fine? Like you would with anything?

Comment: Are you asking about tax? That is, is the point of your question 'How do I comply with tax law if I earn money form selling online curency?'

Answer (score 1):

Let's take Runescape as the example, because there's some guidance about the Dutch legal status of items in that game: the ToS terms do not alter the fact that within Runescape, [items are under the *actual and exclusive control* of a specific player](http://tweakers.net/nieuws/79678/hoge-raad-wegnemen-virtuele-goederen-in-games-is-diefstal.html). That is to say, we can treat these virtual goods as if they were non-virtual.

Now what is the legal status if I try to sell something which by contract I'm forbidden to sell? Such contracts are not illegal per se, but the bar(*) is rather high. As an example, a ticket scalping law is [discussed](https://www.eerstekamer.nl/wetsvoorstel/31461_initiatiefvoorstel_jasper)  because concert and sports ticket vendors currently cannot ban resale by ToS. By analogy, games cannot ban resale by ToS either (There is neither a general law nor a law specific to in-game items).

(*) Resale restrictions can apply to houses as they are a recognized scarce good.